# how to get a value from search input box of ng-select2?

Tags: angular8

installed ng-select2 from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-select2.
I want to get the value from the search input box of the select so I can search by keyword from the server and populate to the selection dropdown.

```
<ng-select2
    [(ngModel)]="
        createJobModel.collectionpickupaddress
    "
    name="collectionpickupaddress"
    id="collectionpickupaddress"
    [data]="exampleData"
    [width]="400"
    [placeholder]="'Select Address'"
>
</ng-select2>
```